# Using NetFwTypeLib to block or unblock ports using firewall settings didn't work on Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp, windows-firewall-api

I was trying to block or unblock using TCP port `80`, with this code:

```
const string guidFWPolicy2 = "{E2B3C97F-6AE1-41AC-817A-F6F92166D7DD}";
const string guidRWRule = "{2C5BC43E-3369-4C33-AB0C-BE9469677AF4}";

Type typeFWPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(guidFWPolicy2));
Type typeFWRule = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(guidRWRule));

INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 =(INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWPolicy2);

INetFwRule newRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWRule);

newRule.Name = "MabuAsTcpLocker_OutBound_Rule";
newRule.Description = "Block outbound traffic  over TCP port 80";
newRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
newRule.RemotePorts = "80";                 
newRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;
newRule.Enabled = true;
newRule.Profiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
newRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;

fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(newRule);
```

This code works just fine on Windows 7, but doesn't work on Windows XP. In my project I just referenced the `NetFwTypeLib` COM library.

The exception says that it couldn't find and instantiate the class with the `{E2B3C97F-6AE1-41AC-817A-F6F92166D7DD}` Guid.

Please can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be writing against the *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security API* which is for Vista onwards. The give away is you referring to `INetFwPolicy2`.

As quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The Windows Firewall API is supported on Windows XP with Service Pack
> 2 (SP2). (For Windows Vista and later, use of the Windows Firewall
> with Advanced Security API is recommended.)

I would have a look into [Using Windows Firewall for Windows XP with SP2 API (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
 which should give you some pointers, or at least some more ammunition for further Google searches.